# Template for asp.net core webapi service

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

Using the asp.net.boilerplate it appears I will always have to choose a front-end option.  It is possible to use this purely for a standardized REST webapi service only?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use ASP.NET Boilerplate templates purely for a Web API service.

For example, choose the ASP.NET Core + Angular template, which provides you with:

```
+-- angular/
|   +-- ...
|   +-- src/
|   +-- ...
|
+-- aspnet-core/
    +-- ...
    +-- src/
    +-- ...
```

And then just ignore the **angular** folder.